# CNAME or 301 redirect for two or more domains with identical keywords

Tags: seo, google, pagerank

I have two domains that contain identical keywords. For example:

1. `applesandoranges.com`
2. `orangesandapples.com`

Is there any SEO advantage/disadvantage if I do not set a `301 redirect` from one of them to the other and choose to set the `CNAME` record instead?

Do the domains share an equal `page rank` and google juice in this kind of configuration?

Comment: CNAME would be better - cleaner. However, keywords is not the way to think here. It is B.S. SEO snake oil and **not** how search engines work. There is no such thing as keyword matching in search. *Really!!* It is far better to have one domain name and to make that one site perform without diluting or dividing the potential.

Comment: Thanks! However, the idea isn't exactly diluting or dividing the potential but using reversible compound words in the domain e.g. `racecar,com` vs `carrace.com` and then setting up CNAME or 301 redirect based on which of the two is more beneficial.

Comment: Having multiple domain names for keyword searches does not work. Especially in the case of your examples. Search engines are semantic engines these days especially with Hummingbird being upgraded to RankBrain. As a result, one domain name will not perform differently or better than the other. I still say use just one. As well, you run into duplicate content issues that require a canonical tag to correct.